# how to "sync" VB Project after dynamically adding a function?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am writing an Excel VBA project that creates new functions during code execution.

The newly added functions need to be able to be executed immediately.

While I do see the new functions added, I receive an "1004" run-time error on the first execution.

The below code adds a new function `testMethod` into an existing `DynamicFunctions` module (if the function is not already there) and executes it.

code snippets taken from  [Dynamic Code Generate & Execute@VBA](https://gist.github.com/dck-jp/15d96e98e7bdb1bfc266) and from [Programming The VBA Editor](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)

The error message:
"Run-time error '1004':
Cannot run the macro 'testMethod'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled"

(notice on second execution, the function already in the module so the code simply executes it and pops the message box)

```
Dim code As String
code = "Public Function testMethod()" & vbNewLine & _
            vbTab & "MsgBox """ & Time & """" & vbNewLine & _
            "End Function"

Dim methodExist As Boolean
methodExist = checkProcName("testMethod")

If (methodExist = False) Then
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Set VBComp = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("DynamicFunctions")
    Call VBComp.CodeModule.AddFromString(code)
End If

Application.Run "testMethod"



Function checkProcName(sProcName As String) As Boolean
' ===========================================================================
' Found on http://www.cpearson.com at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx
' then modified
'
' USAGE:
' to check if a procedure exists, call 'checkProcName' passing
' in the target workbook (which should be open), the Module,
' and the procedure name
'
' ===========================================================================
Dim oVBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

Dim ProcName As String
Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind

checkProcName = False

Set VBProj = ThisWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("DynamicFunctions")
Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

With CodeMod
    LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
    Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines
        ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
        If ProcName = sProcName Then
            checkProcName = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        Debug.Print ProcName
        LineNum = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, ProcKind) + .ProcCountLines(ProcName, ProcKind) + 1
    Loop
End With


End Function
```

Comment: Is your code above in the `DynamicFunctions` module, or in a different one?

Comment: The `checkProcName` is within the `DynamicFunctions`. the others in a different one

Comment: I did a little testing and it worked for me as long as the DynamicFunctions module was reserved for only dynamic code: if you execute anything else from there (or even reference a global stored there) then you see the error you describe.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Thanks Tim, that was indeed the problem. if you wish to add your comment as an answer, I'll approve it

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a specific reason you need to have the *DynamicFunctions* module in your project, you could always create one on the fly, run the code and delete when done.

```
Public Sub CreateModuleRunMethodAndDelete()
    Dim code As String
        code = "Public Function testMethod()" & vbNewLine & _
                vbTab & "MsgBox """ & Time & """" & vbNewLine & _
                "End Function"

    'Create and append code
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject
        With .VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
            .Name = "Temp"
            .CodeModule.AddFromString code
        End With
    End With

    'Run
    Application.Run "testMethod"

    'Delete module
    With ThisWorkbook.VBProject
        .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents("Temp")
     End With
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

Create procedure if not exists and run.

```
Public Sub RunMethod()
    Dim code As String
        code = "Public Function testMethod()" & vbNewLine & _
                vbTab & "MsgBox """ & Time & """" & vbNewLine & _
                "End Function"

    If Not checkProcName("testMethod") Then
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("DynamicFunctions").CodeModule.AddFromString code
    End If

    Application.Run "testMethod"

End Sub
```

Comment: the dynamic code is being extract from an external file - this is time consuming process (over the network, tens of external files...) - i wish to make the "creation" phase sticky... e.g., only 1 time the file will be opened and dynamic code will be created, second and later, the function already exist...

Comment: the above is practically my code as posted in the question - it doesn't address my main problem which is "getting a 1004 run time error on the first execution of the code" - @Kostas did you try it and managed to run it on first time?

Comment: @NirMH Correct, executes with no error. Tested countless times, each time deleting the testMethod's code.